# Recived memory warning and crash when loading many .jpg files with ARC

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have problem with memory. I use ARC. I' m loading .jpgs to UIImageView on my view.

```
Code showing example situation:

//.h file

@interface myClass : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView * back;
}
// don' t have @property
// back is connected in .xib

//.m file
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *  myImg =[UIImage imageNamed:imgName];

    back.image=myImg;
}

-(void) returnToPrevoriousView {
   [self removeFromSuperview];
   back.image = nil;
}
```

The problem is that i come to this view from the other view and imgName can have many values. I can come myClass for example six times then I  have log: **Recieve memory warning** and my app crash.

I think myImg isn' t released from memory? I don' t have any idea how fix it ? JPGs have about 100kb.

PS. When I load .png it' s works(aslo faster) in spite of .png images have usually 600kB. But I think it still don' t release memory ?

Comment: Does this still happen when you remove that code from `viewDidLoad`? Also, why are you using `removeFromSuperview` instead of just resigning the entire controller with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`?

Comment: When I delete back.image=myImg then app works(but i need this image). I add myClass by call [ parent addSubview: myClass ]. Can I do this in other way ? I don' t want navigationController.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if this is related to internal caching in the view controller instead of anything related to the image. You're not resigning the view controller properly, try fixing that first.

Comment: I change addSubview for: [self addChildViewController:myClass] and in out button add: [self removeFromView] and [self removeFromParentViewController]]. Now works. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought that now works. But still don' t work correctly. Just now i Can show more images. If someone have any other idea, please help me.

Comment: Why don't you just use `pushModalViewController` and `dismissViewController`?

Comment: I don' t have navigation Controller.

Comment: That code isn't for navigation controllers. It'll work for any UIViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `UIImage imageNamed:` if you are certain that the image will not be used again within your app. `imageNamed:` uses an internal caching mechanism that will use additional memory.

From the [UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.

Instead use `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` for single use images as those are not cached.

***Note***: only `imageNamed:` will do automatic retina version loading (@2x).

Answer (score 1):

**In General** try to use PNG Images .. since the iOS is optimized to handle PNG images very efficiently ..  and this optimizations is not offered for JPEG Images , when the iOS start to display jpg its requires a much more complicated decoding process which will take more CPU energy.

Answer (score 0):

assign property to IBOutlet back and synthesize it.